# Eclipse CDT - Cannot open include file: 'windows.h' (Microsoft SDK)

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, visual-studio

I'm trying to get Eclipse to build a project which was originally designed using Visual C++ (version 2008). I'm using the Microsoft Visual C++ toolchain.

When I try to build the project, I get the following error:

`C:\...\types.h(25) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory`

I've found some posts suggesting that I should download the Microsoft SDK and add the directory containing windows.h to the path. **The problem is, Microsoft SDK** (at least the version I downloaded, which is Windows SDK for Windows 8.1) **does not contain such file.**

Is there a way to obtain windows.h and all of its underlying headers (assuming that is the problem)? And if that's not the problem, what could be the solution?

Please notice I'm a real beginner to Eclipse and I have never used Visual, so I think there's no such thing as a too detailed answer.

If you need further information or did not understand something I wrote (English is not my mother tongue) please let me know.

Comment: As you say you have the Microsoft Visual C++ toolchain, then "windows.h" is somewhere in it's installation directory structure, have you looked in there?  Also as a beginner why use Eclipse if you already have Microsoft Visual C++?  You are just making things harder for yourself.  Full Visual Studio 2013 (community edition) is available from MS at https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply, but 'windows.h' isn't there neither. The project appears to have been created using VS C++ 2008, so the problem is possibly caused by compatibility issues. I got it to run in VS C++ 2008, but it still does not work in eclipse. P.S. : It is a university project so I have to use eclipse.